# Pull Text from Varying XPath Element based on Header Text

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to pull the Standard Transit from this site, but I cannot reference the element because there is no unique identifier. Additionally, the element's location could change based on the table expanding or contracting.

Is there a way to scrape the date from Standard Transit:

1) based on the header (Standard Transit)
2) without going to the shipment facts tab

I am using Python 3.7 & Chrome

Example: https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=478239726746

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Which element changes location can you specify, please?

Comment: Standard Transit will be in the same table, but the location in the table may change depending on what other elements are being displayed, for different shipments.

Comment: fedex has normal API, which would be much easier to use and more robust than parsing their website

Comment: Can the element Standard Transit be pulled from the API?

Comment: I do not believe you can pull estimated delivery date (Standard Transit) for Ground from the API. If so, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

You don't have to worry about the table changes when you use the below xpath. The xpath will return the date though you are not on "Shipment Facts" tab.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Standard transit ']/ancestor::li/span").get_attribute('textConent')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the response. Unfortunately, the bit of code you posted doesn't return anything.

Comment: hmm, we have to get the textContent rather text, updated the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Your updated solution works for 3 tracking numbers, and then gives an error on "https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=478239726963"

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[.='Standard transit ']/ancestor::li/span"}

Comment: make sure to wait for the element by using the Expected Condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=478239726746")


wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.detailViewTabs_area >ul >li.factsTab > a"))).click()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.dp_facts_area")))

standardTransitDate = wait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//em[contains(.,'Standard transit ')]/following-sibling::span")))

print(standardTransitDate.text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I received the following error when running the code you posted:
  wait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.detailViewTabs_area >ul >li.factsTab > a"))).click()

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.detailViewTabs_area >ul >li.factsTab > a"}

Comment: It was working for me. I have updated the code. Could you please check?